# How to make twisted defer get function result?

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I want to do something in `multiprocessing`, and I want to defer get result, something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from twisted.internet import defer
import time

def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(x)
    return x*x

pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
def get_result(i):
    res = pool.apply_async(f, (i, )) # do work in process pool
    return defer.Deferred(res.get()) # now, I want to make process do something else, so it should not be blocked

def main():
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def _run():
        for i in range(4):
            yield get_result(i)

        reactor.stop()
    reactor.callLater(1, _run)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Pool.apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) has a `callback` arg that you can leverage to start the callback chain in the `Deferred`.
The catch (which is absolutely crucial to remember) is that the Pool-callback-function will be executed **in another thread!**
Therefore, you must call `reactor.callFromThread` when applying the result to the `Deferred` so that the callback chain occurs in the same thread as the `reactor`.
Failure to do this will result in callbacks being executed in a different thread that the reactor has no context into.
Here is a slightly modified example:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
import threading
import time

from twisted.internet import defer, reactor


def f(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x*x

def get_result(pool, i):
    deferred = defer.Deferred()   # create a Deferred that will eventually provide a result
    _set_result = partial(set_result, deferred=deferred)  # pass the Deferred to the apply_async callback
    pool.apply_async(f, args=(i,), callback=_set_result)  # execute in a separate process, supply callback fn
    return deferred

def set_result(result, deferred):
    """
    Set the result in the deferred
    """
    print('Thread ID: %d, Setting result %d' % (threading.get_ident(), result))
    reactor.callFromThread(deferred.callback, result)   # execute the Deferred callback chain from the reactor thread

def display_result(result):
    """
    Just display the result
    """
    print('Thread ID: %d, Display %d' % (threading.get_ident(), result))

def kill_reactor(null):
    print('Thread ID: %d, Stopping reactor' % threading.get_ident())
    reactor.stop()

def main():
    print('Thread ID: %d, Main' % threading.get_ident())
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    d = get_result(pool, 3)
    d.addCallback(display_result)
    d.addCallback(kill_reactor)

    reactor.run()

main()


#---------- OUTPUT ----------#
# Thread ID: 803872, Main
# Thread ID: 533632, Setting result 9
# Thread ID: 803872, Display 9
# Thread ID: 803872, Stopping reactor
```

I've printed the thread id so that you can see that `set_result()` is indeed called in another thread (process?) and not in the main thread, ie reactor thread.
Ommiting `reactor.callFromThread(deferred.callback, result)` in this example will cause the callbacks to executed in a thread that `reactor.stop()` will not work and Twisted throws up vomit (tracebacks) everywhere!
Consider using at [`reactor.spawnProcess`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html) as this will limit mistakes that you (or myself) would make otherwise.
And as always, if you can do whatever it is you're tyring to do, in a single thread and omit `multiprocessing` or `threading`, I'd suggest you do that instead.